# Faz algum sentido existir tags com nome de empresas no site?

Tags: debate, tags

Vi uma pergunta com a tag <kbd>locaweb</kbd> e  reparei que tem outras tags do tipo, com nome de empresa ou um produto muito específico.

Só pra tentar entender o critério, pesquisei por "King Host" ou "Dialhost" e, apesar de ter encontrado conteúdo com nome desses serviços, não existiam tags para as mesmas.

Faz sentido ter uma tag para serviços de hospedagem ou produtos, especificamente?

Sei que existe casos como <kbd>aws</kbd> e <kbd>windows-azure</kbd> no site e isso me deixa com outra dúvida:

Qual critério adotado para permitir ou não uma tag referente a um serviço de hospedagem ou produto específico no site?

Comment: Particularmente acho que faz sentido ter `[aws]` e `[windows-azure]` porque eles fornecem muitos serviços, mas como nunca os usei não sei se seria algo do tipo "suporte técnico", como algumas das perguntas `[locaweb]` parecem ser.

Comment: A King Host é subsidiária da locaweb pelo menos é o que o Google [informa](https://www.google.com/search?sa=X&biw=1366&bih=695&sxsrf=ALeKk01VLGrjEFq5byTu_94iJB47A-B8ZA:1605018481762&q=KingHost&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAOPgE-LWT9c3NDIqrsgozFPiBXEMkw3LCwvLq8y0NDPKrfST83NyUpNLMvPz9POL0hPzMqsSQZxiq-LSpOLMlMzEoszU4kWsHN6Zeeke-cUlABb35VpUAAAA&ved=2ahUKEwjN_Nnjl_jsAhUrK7kGHVsjCK0Qri4wF3oECBwQNQ).

Comment: **Observação**: Modifiquei a pergunta para ficar mais genérica, visto que se aplica a outros casos.

Comment: Considero que os grandões deve ter (AWS, GCP e Azure), o mesmo se aplica a outros cenários, como Firebase, Google Mapas API, etc. Os menores não porque a pergunta criada muito provavelmente será só um help desk

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Num primeiro momento, tomando por base o levantamento inicial, não faz nenhum sentido, praticamente todas caem em duas categorias:

- Suporte fora do nosso escopo (deve ser feito no fornecedor e não aqui)
- Perguntas em que o fornecedor do serviço não faz diferença para a dúvida

Isto se aplica a outros produtos particulares de outras empresas também, como hosts, gateways de pagamento, nomes de produtos muito específicos etc que tendem a atrair perguntas irrelevantes para o escopo.

Eventualmente, se um dia surgir no escopo uma situação em que a tag tenha sentido, ela será criada organicamente (como toda tag deveria ser, acredito eu). Perguntas no escopo devem criar tags, não o inverso.

Ainda, se alguma empresa quiser tag no SOpt deve procurar a Stack Exchange para saber sobre tags patrocinadas (e mesmo assim, só pode ser usada para perguntas que se encaixam no escopo, obviamente).

Já proponho darmos andamento numa revisão extensiva de posts com tags "particulares", principalmente essas com tendência de mau uso, não limitado à empresa mencionada apenas.

**Resumo:**

- Quem deve determinar a necessidade de existir determinada tag são as perguntas válidas dentro do escopo do site.
- Revisando as perguntas com as tags suspeitas, estas terão seu destino natural, seja permanecer ou "perecer".